# Query to group similar columns values based on different other column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to get the information about the legal names which has different system originator and ID. So, can anyone help me with the query?

My Query is :

```
 SELECT ID,
    SystemOriginator,
    LegalName
FROM Institution
ORDER BY LegalName,
    SystemOriginator
```

Test Data:

```
   ID    SystemOriginator   LegalName  
 ------ ------------------ ----------- 
  2382   MLA                FC STONE   
  2382   MLA                FC STONE   
  2171   MLA                XYZ        
  2871   New System         XYZ        
  2171   MLA                XYZ
```

and the result I want to achieve is :

```
   ID    SystemOriginator   LegalName  
 ------ ------------------ ----------- 
  2382   MLA                FC STONE   
  2171   MLA                XYZ        
  2871   New System         XYZ
```

Comment: `select DISTINCT ID,SystemOriginator,LegalName from Institution order by LegalName,SystemOriginator`

Comment: `select DISTINCT * from Institution order by LegalName,SystemOriginator`

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ID,
                SystemOriginator,
                LegalName
from Institution
ORDER BY LegalName, SystemOriginator
```